# Run Oracle Sql Script via Java

Tags: java, oracle, triggers, oracle11g

I wrote a java program to `insert and update` data for oracle database. i need to `DISABLE` some triggers before insert or update data. also need to `ENABLE` previously DISABLED triggers after insert or update data. i wrote two sql scripts as `pre_script.sql` and `post_script.sql` to `DISABLE` and `ENABLE` triggers.

How could i run these files using java ? is there any method to pass these sql files for execute in java ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [run oracle sql script from java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200513/run-oracle-sql-script-from-java)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest option would be to create your SQL scripts as stored procedures or functions in the database, which would then just require a simple call from Java to execute them.

```
CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall("{ call pre_script_as_func() }");
cs.execute();

// do inserts, updates 

cs = conn.prepareCall("{ call post_script_as_func() }");
cs.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
```

Assuming a connection object of `conn`

Create a SQL statement from connection object:

```
Statement DMLString conn.createStatement();
```

Create a string variable and populate with alter trigger statement:

```
String sql = "ALTER TRIGGER [TRIGGER_NAME] DISABLE";
```

Execute the SQL against the DB

```
String  result = DMLString.execute(sql.toString());
```

Comment: Sorry should have mentioned you could read the files (pre_script.sql,post_script.sql) into Java and push each statment to DB using the method above.

Comment: Oh, does anyone know why I got marked down for this answer?  I'm still tweaking my StackOverflow experience....

Comment: Your `ALTER TRIGGER` syntax is incorrect, for one. Should be `ALTER TRIGGER [TRIGGER_NAME] DISABLE`

Comment: @phil - Thanks, I have amended the example above.